# Escaping strings in kotlin to run my os command

Tags: kotlin

So here is a bit of a tricky one.

I've just finished writing myself my first Kotlin script to execute some os commands for me and it works on a basic command.

```
val command = "kubectl get pods"
println(command)
execLocal(command)

    fun execLocal(command: String): String {
        try {
            val commands = ArrayList<String>()
            commands.add("powershell.exe")
            commands.add("-Command")
            commands.add(command)

            val pb = ProcessBuilder(commands)
            
            println("Running: " + pb.command())

            val process = pb.start()
            val result = collectOutput(process.inputStream)

            if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
                println("Failed to execute command: " + pb.command())
                println("Result: " + result)
                val error = collectOutput(process.errorStream)
                println("Error: " + error)
                throw RuntimeException()
            } else {
                println("stdout: " + result)
            }
            return result
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    fun collectOutput(inputStream: InputStream): String {
        val out = StringBuilder()
        val buf: BufferedReader = inputStream.bufferedReader(UTF_8)
        var line: String? = buf.readLine()
        do {
            if (line != null) {
                out.append(line).append("\n")
            }
            line = buf.readLine()
        } while (line != null)
        return out.toString()
    }
```

I have a problem in the snippet above when i change the first line to:

```
val command = "kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[].image}{\\\"\\n\\\"}{end}'"
```

What gets printed as part of line two is:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[].image}{\"\n\"}{end}'
```

When i take that string and run it on the command line it works exactly how i want it to but from the kotlin code i get an error.

```
Error: error: error parsing jsonpath {range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[].image}{\n}{end}, unrecognized character in action: U+005C '\'
```

There is a difference between how kotlin is executing my code and the behaviour if i execute myself as a command which I'm hoping you experts might be able to help me solve.

thanks

Comment: You need to add the three words in command separately to the ArrayList. When you add "kubectl get pods" it gets quoted as one string because of the spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a raw String. In Kotlin it is delimited by a triple quote (`"""`), contains no escaping and can contain newlines and any other characters. This means you can do something as follows:

```kotlin
val command = """kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[].image}{
    |}{end}'""".trimMargin()
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion but it still did not work. After spending about an hour mucking around i called the quits and have just decided to go with a csv string. I can't get the expression right.